# Parsing child node with own namespace in DOM4j with Java

Tags: xpath, namespaces, dom4j

I hope someone can help fix my foobar.  I have been working on a DOM4j parser for about a month to extract over 500 data elements from an XML file using XPATH .  Unfortunately I used an old test file as a model to create my code and only found the error of my way after plugging in a production file.  Here is a small sample of my code.  As you can see from the Hashmap, there are several namespaces utilized within the full XML. I cut the code down to only extract 3 elements.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.XPath;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

public class CLOBTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         File inputFile = new File("C:/test.xml");
         //File inputFile = new File("C:/test1.xml");
         SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
         Document document = reader.read( inputFile );

         Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

         map.put("exch", "http://at.dsh.cms.gov/exchange/1.0");
         map.put("ext", "http://at.dsh.cms.gov/extension/1.0");
         map.put("hix-core", "http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-core");
         map.put("hix-ee", "http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-ee");
         map.put("hix-pm", "http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-pm");
         map.put("nc", "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
         map.put("niem-core", "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
         map.put("s", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0");
         map.put("scr", "http://niem.gov/niem/domains/screening/2.1");
         map.put("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


         XPath Request = DocumentHelper.createXPath("//exch:AccountTransferRequest");
         Request.setNamespaceURIs(map);

         Node request =  Request.selectSingleNode(document);

         System.out.println("  ID:        \t" + request.valueOf("ext:TransferHeader/ext:TransferActivity/niem-core:ActivityIdentification/niem-core:IdentificationID")); 
         System.out.println("  First Name:\t" + request.valueOf("hix-core:Person/niem-core:PersonName/niem-core:PersonGivenName")); 
         System.out.println("  Last Name: \t" + request.valueOf("hix-core:Person/niem-core:PersonName/niem-core:PersonSurName")); 

      } catch (DocumentException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

The sample XML file (test.xml) gives the correct result of:

```
ID:         XXX012345
First Name: gina
Last Name:  davis
```

test.xml

```
 <H15>
 <requestMSG>
 <exch:AccountTransferRequest xmlns:exch="http://at.dsh.cms.gov/exchange/1.0" xmlns:hix-core="http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-core" xmlns:niem-core="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:ext="http://at.dsh.cms.gov/extension/1.0" ext:atVersionText="2.3">
 <ext:TransferHeader>
 <ext:TransferActivity>
 <niem-core:ActivityIdentification xmlns:niem-core="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
 <niem-core:IdentificationID>XXX012345</niem-core:IdentificationID>
 </niem-core:ActivityIdentification>
 </ext:TransferActivity>
 </ext:TransferHeader>
 <hix-core:Person xmlns:hix-core="http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-core" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" s:id="Mom">
 <niem-core:PersonName xmlns:niem-core="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
 <niem-core:PersonGivenName>gina</niem-core:PersonGivenName>
 <niem-core:PersonSurName>davis</niem-core:PersonSurName>
 </niem-core:PersonName>
 </hix-core:Person>
 </exch:AccountTransferRequest>
 </requestMSG>
 </H15>
```

However, if the element exch:AccountTransferRequest does NOT contain all the namespace references, I get an Unbounded prefix error on the child nodes. I had assumed the Hashmap assignment to the Request XPath had taken care of all the prefix binding.  I realized after trying it on a production file (test1.xml) that did not have the full complement of URIs in the exch:AccountTransferRequest element that I was wrong.

test1.xml

```
 <H15>
 <requestMSG>
 <exch:AccountTransferRequest xmlns:exch="http://at.dsh.cms.gov/exchange/1.0" xmlns:ext="http://at.dsh.cms.gov/extension/1.0" ext:atVersionText="2.3">
 <ext:TransferHeader>
 <ext:TransferActivity>
 <niem-core:ActivityIdentification xmlns:niem-core="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
 <niem-core:IdentificationID>XXX012345</niem-core:IdentificationID>
 </niem-core:ActivityIdentification>
 </ext:TransferActivity>
 </ext:TransferHeader>
 <hix-core:Person xmlns:hix-core="http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-core" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" s:id="Mom">
 <niem-core:PersonName xmlns:niem-core="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
 <niem-core:PersonGivenName>gina</niem-core:PersonGivenName>
 <niem-core:PersonSurName>davis</niem-core:PersonSurName>
 </niem-core:PersonName>
 </hix-core:Person>
 </exch:AccountTransferRequest>
 </requestMSG>
 </H15>
```

test1.xml result:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dom4j.XPathException: Exception occurred evaluting XPath: ext:TransferHeader/ext:TransferActivity/niem-core:ActivityIdentification/niem-core:IdentificationID. Exception: XPath expression uses unbound namespace prefix niem-core
    at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.handleJaxenException(DefaultXPath.java:374)
    at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.valueOf(DefaultXPath.java:185)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.valueOf(AbstractNode.java:191)
    at CLOBTest.main(CLOBTest.java:41)
```

Now, how do I extract the values of the child nodes that have their own namespace?  Is there a way to do it while still going through the request node? I would like to salvage some of my effort if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  Just had to cast the request node to an element and add all the namespaces.  Once I used the element in an output, the entire document recognized them.

```
         Element test = (Element) request;
         test.addNamespace("exch", "http://at.dsh.cms.gov/exchange/1.0");
         test.addNamespace("ext", "http://at.dsh.cms.gov/extension/1.0");
         test.addNamespace("hix-core", "http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-core");
         test.addNamespace("hix-ee", "http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-ee");
         test.addNamespace("hix-pm", "http://hix.cms.gov/0.1/hix-pm");
         test.addNamespace("nc", "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
         test.addNamespace("niem-core", "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
         test.addNamespace("s", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0");
         test.addNamespace("scr", "http://niem.gov/niem/domains/screening/2.1");
         test.addNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

         System.out.println("  ID:                                             \t"+test.valueOf("ext:TransferHeader/ext:TransferActivity/niem-core:ActivityIdentification/niem-core:IdentificationID"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you need to create further `XPath` objects and each time set the namespace context e.g.

```
     XPath Request = DocumentHelper.createXPath("//exch:AccountTransferRequest");
     Request.setNamespaceURIs(map);

     Node request =  Request.selectSingleNode(document);

     XPath idRequest = DocumentHelper.createXPath("ext:TransferHeader/ext:TransferActivity/niem-core:ActivityIdentification/niem-core:IdentificationID");
     idRequest.setNamespaceURIs(map);

     System.out.println("  ID:        \t" + idRequest.selectSingleNode(request).getText());
```

Comment: Fantastic.  This should allow me to salvage a great deal but still going to be a lot of recoding. I'll let you know how it turns out.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I've been trying this solution for over a week now.  I made it through a few of my classes but now I've hit a snag.  When I have an XPATH that starts in one node but references another node, I have no way of binding the namespace of the second node ahead of time. Is there a way to select a node from an XML document, add all possible namespace attributes to it, and pass it as a Node to another class with the namespace attributes still attached?  Do I need to cast from Node to Element or vise-versa?